# Xcode auto save file when navigating away

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, indexing, autosave

These are the cases when Xcode saves the files:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingFileSaving.html

Is there a way to tell Xcode to save file each time when I navigate away? If the file is not saved, its content is not indexed, then it won't autocomplete. I always start typing, then I realize it's not indexed yet, then I press ⌘-B, then it saves and indexes, but adds error. Now I can type further, it autocompletes, but the error message appears with the previous starting letters, that it doesn't have any member, so it's a mess.

An autosave would be handy, or any other solutions for the problem above?

Comment: Offtop: I already have reflex ⌘-S after each line of code :)